# Error importing "enchant" in google colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I did the following in google colab notebook and get an error. Any idea?

```
%pip install pyenchant
import enchant
```

and get the following error:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 import enchant

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/enchant/_enchant.py in ()
159         """
160     )
--> 161     raise ImportError(msg)
162
163

ImportError: The 'enchant' C library was not found and needs to be installed.
See  https://pyenchant.github.io/pyenchant/install.html
for details

Answer (score 5):

After lots of research, I found the solution [here](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/441).

Run this code on goggle colab before `import enchant`

```
!apt update
!apt install enchant --fix-missing
!apt install -qq enchant
!pip install pyenchant
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes enchant doesnt work on Google colab because of C libraries. You can use Jupyter notebook for this library and it will work just fine.

Comment: Hello, tried that. Still the same error.

Comment: Now try this. i updated it

Comment: Install it with ```!pip install pyenchant``` and run import enchant